# How to identify each key pressed event in ag grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

when i type alphabet "A" in Text field then i want to send that char to type script ,

FYI,
my goal is "i want to send each and every char to type script when i press key from keyboard"

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 2):

Working Example of [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-jbcxpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You can use like this...

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 500px; height: 150px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    (cellKeyPress)="onCellKeyPress($event)"
    [modules]="modules">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

here `cellKeyPress` event is fire for every cell and then our custom `onCellKeyPress($event)` is called. then in your component.ts you use...

```
onCellKeyPress(e){
  console.log(e.event.key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear below mentioned example is working fine in stackBlitz but in my code onCellKeyPress is not firing on edit .. is it mandatory to use [modules]=“modules”?

Comment: `[modules] = "modules" is called property binding from `.ts file` to `html Template` thats way you can say html that `<ag-grid-angular>` is part of `AllCommunityModules` of `ag-grid` modules, by setting property in .ts file with `modules = AllCommunityModules` and this property value of modules are passing to html using property binding of angular `[modules] = "modules"`

Comment: But it’s throwing error like can’t bind to ‘module’ since it’s not a known property of ‘ag-grid-angular’

Comment: import ag-module in your own module or app.module.ts file..  `import { AgGridModule } from '@ag-grid-community/angular';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AgGridModule.withComponents([]) ],`

Comment: How to call keypressed event without using  @ag-grid-community/angular

Comment: its defined in `ag-grid` component so you have to use it

Comment: You can also define the onCellKeyPress event in the grid options. Here's an explanation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/keyboard-navigation/#keyboard-events

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following code:

app.component.html

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="getLastCharacter($event)">
```

app.component.ts

```
getLastCharacter($event) {
  console.log($event.target.value[$event.target.value.length - 1]);
  return $event.target.value[$event.target.value.length - 1]
}
```

This function will always return you the last character you added in the text input and you can do whatever you want in TS.

If you want to send the whole string you can achieve it like that

app.component.html

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="getLastCharacter($event)">
```

app.component.ts

```
getLastCharacter($event) {
  console.log($event.target.value);
  return $event.target.value;
}
```